# Mockito conditions for several arguments

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I'm trying to mock the results of a method. There should be two variations of the result:

```
Mockito.when(class.method(a,b)).thenReturn(c);
```

- if `a-b` equals 20
- if `a-b` is not 20.

How can I achieve to write two different statements and return different results?

P.S. I know how to user a condition for one argument. For example:

```
class MyCondition extends ArgumentMatcher<AClass> {
    public boolean matches(Object sd) {
           boolean toReturn = (sd instanceof AClass) && (sd >15);
           return toReturn;
           }
    } 


Mockito.when(class.method(Mockito.argThat(new MyCondition()),b)).thenAnswer(
    new Answer<BClass>() {
        public BClass answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
             return new BClass();
        }
    });
```

But how can I build a condition for TWO method arguments?

Comment: Maybe mockito isn't the best tool to use here. You could always extend the class and override the method with your desired if statements.

Comment: You can always use an `Answer` to encode your logic.

Comment: I want to test the class which uses exactly this method and simulate the action of the method.

Comment: @AndyTurner, I now thet there is a possibility to user answer, but usually the condition could be set only for one argument (with Mockito.argThat). My queation is how can I build a condition for two arguments.

Comment: Although the Answer answer is correct, I'm wondering what you want to do here. Is your class under test nondeterministic, since `a` and `b`'s value cannot be determined from the input? That is strange, and might be something to be mocked out by itself. Testcases are usually deterministic / static, and using this answer does not make it deterministic at all. If your test case fails, was it because 20 was returned, or -20? You can't tell, since your testcase covers BOTH, which makes it harder to debug...

Comment: @KoosGadellaa is correct.  A test case that requires both these conditions to be set up is testing too much.  Perhaps if you break this test case down into simpler cases, you won't need such a complex set-up for your mock.

Comment: The method that I mock is used in 10 test cases. The values a and b are deterministic, but two write a line about their difference is shorter than to list all the possibilities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an [`Answer`](https://googletesting.blogspot.co.uk/2014/03/whenhow-to-use-mockito-answer.html):

```
Mockito.when(instance.method(Mockito.anyInt(), Mockito.anyInt()))
    .thenAnswer(
        new Answer<Integer>() {
          @Override public Integer answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
            int a = (Integer) invocation.getArguments()[0];
            int b = (Integer) invocation.getArguments()[1];
            if (a - b == 20) {
              return ...;
            } else {
              return ...;
            }
          }
        });
```